# Cassandra compilation issue Ant

Tags: ant, compilation, cassandra

I have downloaded the cassandra source from git repo git://git.apache.org/cassandra.git and tried to compile using ant. But it throws up following error, how can I resolve this issue?

```
taskdef class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.PropertyFile cannot be found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this guide](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html). It tells you how to install ant's optional tasks, which have the missing class.